# How to use template param to define the signature of a member function which delegates for one or more boost functors

Tags: c++, templates, boost, functor

I believe there should be a way to do this with boost bind or lambda, but I'm coming up empty.  Any help would be appreciated.

Let's say I'm implementing an observer pattern.  I'm attempting to write a generalized publisher class whose template parameter defines the signature of the subscriber callbacks.  Here is a simplified example of the publisher class:

```
template <class T>
class Publisher
{
public:
    void Subscribe(boost::function<T> callback)
    {
        _callbacks.push_back(callback);
    }
private:
    std::list< boost::function<T> > _callbacks;
};
```

Assume I want to make a publisher who notifies its subscribers with float and int values.  I would instantiate the publisher like so:

```
Publisher<void(float,int)> publisher;
```

**Now here's my problem**.  I want to have a method in Publisher called "Notify" that has the same signature as the callbacks.  Its purpose is to traverse the list of callbacks and invoke them with the arguments.

In the case of the float and int signature above, I'd want to function to look like:

```
{
    void Notify(float floatVal, int intVal)
    {
        std::list< boost::function<T> >::iterator iter = _callbacks.begin();

        while (iter != _callbacks.end())
        {
            *iter(floatVal, intVal);
            ++iter;
        }
    }
 }
```

In the generalized case, this is difficult because "T" can represent any function signature type.  I need a way to declare "Notify" so that it has the same arity as the callbacks and acts as a pass-through for each callback in the list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can either define `Notify` as variadic template (c++11), or define a lot template overloads to cover all the arities you wish. (BTW, it looks like you try to reinvent Boost.Signals2.)

Comment: Thanks @IgorR.  I can use variadic templates, but am also interested how to do it without C++11 support.  I'm thinking there should be a way of doing this using some combination of Boost Function Types and MPL or Fusion.  (I initially implemented this using Boost Signals2, but I require special behavior to safely manage the lifetimes of the publisher and subscribers.  Signals2 also has some support for this, but there were limitations.)